# ¿Como obtener los valores de una consulta en odoo-python para transfórmalos a JSON?

Tags: python, rest, odoo

Estoy creando un addon en odoo para obtener unos datos y comunicarlos a través de un controller. Obtengo los datos que necesito desde la BD correctamente pero a la hora de transfórmalos con `json.dumps()` obtengo el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Object of type product.template is not JSON serializable - - -

Así que decidí construir directamente un diccionario de esta manera:

```py
    def cargarDiccionario(self, productos):

        productos_dict = {
            'skus': []
        }

        for producto in productos:
            d = {
                "name": producto.name,
                "categ_id": producto.categ_id.name,
                "booking_rom_num": producto.booking_rom_num,
                "booking_floor": producto.booking_floor,
                "booking_area": producto.booking_area,
                "booking_lookout_area": producto.booking_lookout_area,
                "is_booking_type": producto.is_booking_type,
                "website_url": producto.website_url,
                "booking_plan_ids": [x.id for x in producto.booking_plan_ids],
                "product_template_image_ids": [
                    x.id for x in producto.product_template_image_ids],
                "image_1024": self.imagen_procesar(producto.image_1024),
                "description": producto.description,
                "cost_currency_id": [x for x in producto.cost_currency_id],
                
            }

            productos_dict['skus'].append(d)

        return productos_dict
```

Ahora me encuentro con que `producto.cost_currenci_id` contiene elementos que no se como estan nombrados y necesito extraerlos, por ejemplo:

```json
//Cost prodia contener
{
  id:producto.cost_currency_id.id,
  currenci:producto.cost_currenci_id.name,
  price:producto.cost_currency_id.price,

}
```

¿Como puedo conocer los valores que `producto.cost_currency_id` como `.id`, `.name`, `.price` desde la consola? Y si es posible, ver el valor con el que vienen. Similar a lo que pasa con `console.log(miObjeto)` en javascript.

---

#### Edit

No se como acceder al modelo puesto que la consulta se realiza asi:

```py
from odoo import http

class OdooController(http.Controller):

    @http.route("/barriotec/skus", auth="public", )
    def index(self, **kw):
        self.auth()

        productos = http.request.env['product.template'].search([
            ["is_booking_type", "=", True],
            # ["categ_id", "=", categoriaId],
        ])

        
        self.auth(login=False)

        datos = json.dumps(self.cargarDiccionario(productos))
        return http.Response(
            datos,
            status=200,
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo, aunque seguramente existen mejores o tal vez más [*pytónicas*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic), sería imprimiendo los atributos del objeto mediante el uso del método incorporado [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). Por ejemplo, la siguiente función muestra todos los atributos de un objeto:

```py
def dump(obj):
    for attr in dir(obj):
        print("obj.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))
```

Sin embargo esta función no sólo muestra los atributos propios del objeto sino todos aquellos heredados, como `__class__, __dict__, __hash__` y un gran etc.

Una forma de evitar que muestre todos los [*Dunder methods*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/) es aplicar una condición, por ejemplo, en el siguiente código se hace exactamente eso:

```py
def dump(obj):
  for attr in dir(obj):
    if not '__' in attr:
      print("obj.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))

class Legna:
  loves = ["Javascript", "Typescript"]
  hates = ["Python"]

legna = Legna()

dump(legna)
```

El resultado del código anterior se puede ver así:

```py
obj.hates = ['Python']
obj.loves = ['Javascript', 'Typescript']
```

Una mejora al código mostrado anteriormente sería inspeccionar el atributo [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) del objeto, que contiene todos los atributos *writables* (ojo con esto) del objeto.

Por ejemplo:

```py
def dump(obj):
    d = getattr(obj, '__dict__')
    print(d)


class Legna:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loves = ["Javascript", "Typescript"]
        self.hates = ["Python"]

    is_good_programmer = True

legna = Legna()

dump(legna)
```

El resultado de esto es el siguiente:

```py
{'loves': ['Javascript', 'Typescript'], 'hates': ['Python']}
```

Como vemos, el atributo `is_good_programmer` no se muestra en el diccionario `__dict__` del objeto.

También tenemos situaciones donde el atributo `__dict__` no está presente o simplemente está vacío. Por ejemplo:

```py
def dump(obj):
    d = getattr(obj, '__dict__')
    print(d)


class Legna:
    loves = ["Javascript", "Typescript"]
    hates = ["Python"]
    is_good_programmer = True

legna = Legna()

dump(legna)
```

El resultado sería:

```py
{}
```

Sabiendo todo esto, podríamos escribir un método que tomara en cuenta esta situación, devolviendo tanto los atributos modificables del objeto, como aquellos que no lo son. Además, podemos usar la librería `pprint` para mostrar la salida de una forma más bonita:

```py
import pprint

def dump(obj):
    d = {}
    for attr in dir(obj):
        if not '__' in attr:
            d[attr] = getattr(obj, attr)
    pprint.pprint(d)


class Legna:
    is_good_programmer = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.loves = ["Javascript", "Typescript"]
        self.hates = ["Python"]


legna = Legna()

dump(legna)
```

El resultado debe verse así:

```py
{'hates': ['Python'],
 'is_good_programmer': True,
 'loves': ['Javascript', 'Typescript']}
```

Con esto ya tienes una forma muy básica de mostrar los atributos de un objeto.

**NOTA**

Recuerda que en el último método estamos mostrando los atributos modificables y los que no lo son. Toma en cuenta los temas de herencia y propiedades estáticas de una Clase y cómo las mismas son accesibles únicamente desde la Clase pero no desde la instancia. Tal vez te interese sólo mostrar los atributos listados en el objeto `__dict__`, si el mismo está presente.

Comment: Buena respuesta! Hubiera dicho algo similar, pero no entendía bien la pregunta. Lo unico que tengo para comentar es que tu forma de hacerlo haría que atributos como "hola__mundo" no se imprimiesen. Podrías hacer una condición que valide si la cadena empiesa y termina con __ haciendo `if(not (attr.startswith("__") and attr.endswith("__")))`.

Comment: Pero esto te deja pasar todos los que empiezan con `__` y `_`. Por lo que una condición para evitar todo atributo interno sería `if(not attr.startswith("_"))`

Comment: @DanteS lo sé, y estoy de acuerdo contigo al 100%. Sin embargo, siendo un poco pragmáticos, ¿quién usaría dobles guiones bajos para propiedades de una Clase si no deseara que la misma fuese un Dunder Method? Además, usar doble guión bajo en medio del nombre de una propiedad también sería poco común, sobre todo entre los entendidos en el lenguaje. Pero buena observación la que haces, y precisamente por ello digo al inicio de mi respuesta que seguramente hay formas mejores o más *pytónicas* de hacer esto, ya que yo soy muy Junior en este lenguaje. ;)

Comment: Yo pensé lo mismo, sería raro que alguien usara doble guion bajo dentro del nombre. Sin embargo, en mi opinion, hay que tener en cuenta todos los escenarios. Nadie nace sabiendo c: Yo te hacia propuestas para mejorar tu respuesta!

Comment: Pensandolo bien, incluso mi forma falla en algo, pues podría haber "dunder methods" falsos, como `__color_del_mar__`, dando un falso positivo, pero eso sería una muy mala practica... Pero el punto es reducir la posibilidad de falsos positivos.

Comment: @MauricioContreras La respuesta cubre la necesidad. No veo necesario, en una fase tan temprana,  optimizar el código.  Gracias!.